# Python making a counter

Tags: python, counter

I've been writing code for a rock, paper, scissors game. I have to keep track of the user's wins, losses, and draws. I am running into a problem with the variables wins, losses, and draws being reset to zero. There is a second part of the function that does the same but assigns the corresponding variable as 1.

```
def user_choice():
    print("Choice must be Rock, Paper, or Scissors.")
    users_choice = input("Enter your choice here: ")

    if users_choice == "Rock":
        print("You chose Rock")
        player_choice = "Rock"
        computer_choice(player_choice)
    elif users_choice == "Paper":
        print("You chose Paper")
        player_choice = "Paper"
        computer_choice(player_choice)
    elif users_choice == "Scissors":
        print("You chose Scissors")
        player_choice = "Scissors"
        computer_choice(player_choice)
    else:
        print("Error: Choice must be one of the following: Rock, Paper, or Scissors")
        user_choice()


def computer_choice(player_choice):
    #This is the program's randomly generated number, from here on out the programm will be refered to as Computer.
    computer_generated_number = random.randint(1, 3)
    player_choice = player_choice

    if computer_generated_number == 1:
        computer_choice = "Rock"
        game(player_choice , computer_choice)
    elif computer_generated_number == 2:
        computer_choice = "Paper"
        game(player_choice , computer_choice)
    elif computer_generated_number == 3:
        computer_choice = "Scissors"
        game(player_choice , computer_choice)


def game(player_choice , computer_choice):
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    draws = 0

    if wins or losses or draws >= 1:
        if player_choice == computer_choice:
            print("It's a draw!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            draws = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Rock" and computer_choice == "Scissors":
            print("Rock smashes scissors!")
            print("You won!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            wins = wins + 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Paper" and computer_choice == "Rock":
            print("Paper covers rock!")
            print("You won!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            wins = wins + 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Scissors" and computer_choice == "Paper":
            print("Scissors cut paper!")
            print("You won!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            wins = wins + 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Rock" and computer_choice == "Paper":
            print("Paper covers rock!")
            print("You lost")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            losses = losses + 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Paper" and computer_choice == "Scissors":
            print("Scissors cuts paper!")
            print("You lost")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            losses = losses + 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Scissors" and computer_choice == "Rock":
            print("Rock smashes scissors!")
            print("You lost")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            losses = losses + 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

    if wins or losses or draws == 0:
        if player_choice == computer_choice:
            print("It's a draw!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            draws = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Rock" and computer_choice == "Scissors":
            print("Rock smashes scissors!")
            print("You won!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            wins = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Paper" and computer_choice == "Rock":
            print("Paper covers rock!")
            print("You won!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            wins = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Scissors" and computer_choice == "Paper":
            print("Scissors cut paper!")
            print("You won!")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            wins = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Rock" and computer_choice == "Paper":
            print("Paper covers rock!")
            print("You lost")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            losses = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Paper" and computer_choice == "Scissors":
            print("Scissors cuts paper!")
            print("You lost")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            losses = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")

        elif player_choice == "Scissors" and computer_choice == "Rock":
            print("Rock smashes scissors!")
            print("You lost")
            user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Answer must be a yes or no. ")
            losses = 1

            if user_input == "Yes" or user_input == "yes":
                user_choice()
            elif user_input == "No" or user_input == "no":
                print("You've won" , wins , "times")
                print("You've lost" , losses , "times")
                print("And you've come to a draw" , draws, "times")
                print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Are you trying to run this function multiple times?

Comment: I have tried using a while statement, and I tried to see if I could circumnavigate the variables after the initial assigning

Comment: Can you show us the `user_choice()` function?

Comment: I am trying to call back to a previous function if the user says Yes or yes on playing again

Comment: you should use a return statement at the end of your function with the win,loss, and draw stats

Comment: My guess is that you are calling `game()` from `user_choice()` which then resets all of the variables back to 0.

Comment: You can reduce the code duplication by using `if player_choice == computer_choice:` to detect a tie, and or the pattern `if A and B or B and C or C and A:` for the wins, else it is a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a simplified "architecture". Your functions to get the user and computer choices should return values that can be compared.

```
import random

CHOICES = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')

def get_user_choice():
    choice = input('Rock, paper, or scissors? ')
    choice = choice.lower().strip()
    if choice not in CHOICES:
        print('Please select one of rock, paper, or scissors')
        choice = get_user_choice()
    return choice

def get_computer_choice():
    return random.choice(CHOICES)

def play_round():
    user_choice = get_user_choice()
    computer_choice = get_computer_choice()
    print('You selected', user_choice)
    print('Computer selected', computer_choice)
    # Compare choices here
    # Return value indicating win, loss, or draw

def play():
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    draws = 0
    result = play_round()
    # Update wins, losses, or draws according to the result
    # Prompt user to play again or quit
    return wins, losses, draws

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wins, losses, draws = play()
    # Report wins, losses, and draws
```